Request to solve the error for power flow
I am trying to optimize a small power system network using the GLPK solver in PyPSA. After running LOPF, thee results are coming in terms of real power and bus voltage angle, as it is likely considering the assumption of voltage magnitude of 1, and neglecting the reactive power. I also tried to follow the documentation  "Non-linear power flow after LOPF" but failed to get the results for all parameters, such as P,Q,voltage magnitude and angle. I want to attach my CSV files along with the .ipynb.where should I attach the files, so that someone can help me. Kindly help me in fixing the errors and get the results of power flow.
After running LOPF with GLPK solver, I am trying to run pf, but its showing a huge error.
